# Group the viewbag items while rendering in view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC. We have a list of owners. Each owner has details like name, address and class(based on his income). In MVC controller, I am storing the list of owners in a viewbag. I want to group the owners who are having the same class while rendering in the view.

can you please help me in segregating the owners like 
class A:
owner1
owner5

class B:
owner4

class C:
owner2
owner3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not strictly related to MVC. you have to put your objects into three different lists. (I am assuming you have a class named Owner that has the properties mentioned).

you can do this in your controller action method, like

```
ViewBag.listA = originallist.Where(c => c.class == "a")
ViewBag.listB = originallist.Where(c => c.class == "b")
```

and then in you view you will have blocks like

```
@foreach(Owner owner in ViewBag.listA)
{
    <div> your text here @owner.Name </div
}
```

you can also do the query part in the view and keep your list as it is in the controller.